# Embedding Intrinsically Sized View Breaks Animation

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout

I have built a test project to show what the goal is vs. what I currently have happening. The gif on the left shows exactly what I want the ending appearance to be. It is constructed with a single traditional view hierarchy. I need to achieve this with the pink view being [an embedded/contained view](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html). My attempts so far have only gotten me to the gif on the right.

The way the (pink) contained view grows is possibly an important detail: the blue subview changes it's height, and the whole apparatus gets a new intrinsic size because of all the connected vertical constraints. As you would expect, this is a simplification of my actual app, but I think it has all the important bits.

[image: Ideal visual outcome: Smooth animation of both the contained view and it's siblings in the containing context]
[image: As is: The inner parts of the contained view animate well, but the sibling view does not animate.]

The main things I see that are strange:

1. The yellow/orange "other" view is not animating at all.
2. The pink contained view is animating nicely for it's own part, but it is animating it's position, even though it's frame has the same origin before and after the animation as shown here:
   [image: Before and after the animation, the frame has the same origin]

Here is the Storyboard of the right gif. Both the container view in the "parent" scene and the top view in the "child" scene have `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` set to false with runtime attributes.

[image: Xcode storyboard showing embedded view setup and constraints]

The question then: **What must I change about my configuration to get all affected layout changes to animate (properly) when I have a size change in an intrinsically-sized and contained view? **

**Edit: Tried manual embed**
Since posting the question, I have tried a manual View Controller Containment strategy, and I got the exact same results as with the Storyboard technique, which is ultimately a good sign for the platform. There was 1 fewer view in the total hierarchy, but it didn't seem to make a difference.

**Edit: Bounty and project**
I have added a 100 point bounty to attract attention. I have also uploaded my sample project to [this github repo](https://github.com/ctrahey/SO_embeded_intrinsic_animate). Check it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing your animation block in InnerViewController as follows does the trick.

```
var isCollapsed = false {
    didSet {
        let factor:CGFloat = isCollapsed ? 1.5 : 0.66
        let existing = innerViewHeightConstraint.constant
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) {
            self.innerViewHeightConstraint.constant = existing * factor
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            self.parent?.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
}
```

The key difference is `self.parent?.view.layoutIfNeeded()`, which tells the embedding view controller to update the constraints as part of the animation, instead of immediately before the start of the animation.

Comment: Thank you Sam! I ended up needing to bubble this up (in my actual project, there are several levels of containment). Wrapped this up into a UIVC extension: `func bubbleLayoutIfNeeded() {
        view.layoutIfNeeded()
        parent?.bubbleLayoutIfNeeded()
    }`